# Store a session variable in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I'm trying to grab a session variable in my javascript, but have some problems getting it right..
I didn't get that to work, so instead i tried to store it in a hidden variable in HTML first, but i dont know how to store a session variable there.. 
Can anyone guide me to the right path?

The code (HTML file): ($_SESSION["price1"] is equal to "20.00")

```
<input type="hidden" id="price" value="$_SESSION["price"]"/>
```

The code in javascript:

```
    var sessionValue = document.getElementById("price").value;
```

What to do?

Comment: use `price1` instead of `price` in your html

Comment: try `document.getElementById("price").defaultValue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed PHP tags `<?php` and `echo`, change to:

```
<input type="hidden" id="price" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["price"]; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

What everyone bellow mentioned is perfectly true, inside HTML you can just wrap stuff in `<?php echo $_SESSION['price']; ?>` and it will work (notice the `<?php` tags)

However, the right way to do this -- considering you want to pass a PHP variable (in your case a session variable) to javascript is to directly insert it into a javascript variable instead of accessing the DOM. This way, you also have it instantly and don't have to wait for the DOM to be loaded

```
<script>
var price = '<?php echo $_SESSION["price"]; ?>';
alert('The price is: ' + price);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
<input type="hidden" id="price" value="$_SESSION["price"]"/>
```

Should be:

```
<input type="hidden" id="price" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["price"];?>"/>
```

You are missing the php tags

Answer (score 1):

change,

```
<input type="hidden" id="price" value="$_SESSION["price"]"/>
```

To,

```
<input type="hidden" id="price" value='<?php echo $_SESSION["price"]; ?>'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab your session variable in JavaScript using this:

```
var my_session_price = "<?php echo $_SESSION["price"]; ?>";
```